# When would GHC cache the computation of a local definition in a function when called multiple times

Tags: performance, haskell

Consider the following definitions:

```hs
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Computing the sum inside, without lambdas
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

in_no_lambda :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
in_no_lambda xs = fmap (aux_in_no_lambda xs)

aux_in_no_lambda :: [Int] -> Int -> Int
aux_in_no_lambda xs i = let sum_xs = {-# SCC "sum_in_no_lambda" #-} sum xs
                        in sum_xs + i

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Computing the sum inside, using lambdas
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
in_lambda :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
in_lambda xs = fmap (aux_in_lambda xs)

aux_in_lambda :: [Int] -> Int -> Int
aux_in_lambda xs = let sum_xs = {-# SCC "sum_in_lambda" #-} sum xs
                   in \i -> sum_xs + i

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Computing the sum outside
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
out :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
out xs = fmap (aux_out sum_xs)
  where sum_xs = {-# SCC "sum_out" #-} sum xs

aux_out :: Int -> Int -> Int
aux_out sum_xs i = sum_xs + i
```

While these are all equivalent, their runtime performance (apparently) is not:

```
COST CENTRE          MODULE                SRC                       no.     entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc

MAIN                 MAIN                  <built-in>                122           0   14.1    0.0   100.0  100.0
 CAF                 Main                  <entire-module>           243           0    0.0    0.0    85.9  100.0
  main               Main                  app/Main.hs:(6,1)-(12,22) 244           1   11.8   18.7    85.9  100.0
   in_lambda         Lib                   src/Lib.hs:26:1-38        248           1   20.6   27.1    26.3   27.1
    sum_in_lambda    Lib                   src/Lib.hs:29:61-66       249           1    5.7    0.0     5.7    0.0
   in_no_lambda      Lib                   src/Lib.hs:16:1-44        246           1   22.2   27.1    22.9   27.1
    sum_in_no_lambda Lib                   src/Lib.hs:19:69-74       247    10000001    0.8    0.0     0.8    0.0
   out               Lib                   src/Lib.hs:(36,1)-(37,45) 250           1   19.2   27.1    24.9   27.1
    sum_out          Lib                   src/Lib.hs:37:40-45       251           1    5.7    0.0     5.7    0.0
```

The profile data above raises two main questions:

0. Does the compiler applies different rules in `in_no_lambda` and in `in_lambda` which cause `sum_xs` to be computed once in the latter case? If so what are these rules? (and what would be an easy way to verify this empirically)
1. Cost center `sum_in_no_lambda` is entered multiple times, however the `%time` spent in this cost center seems to be lower than in `sum_in_lambda` and `sum_in_lambda` that are only entered once! How can this be explained?

Comment: Rule of thumb: `let` allocates on the heap, and the bodies of lambdas are not evaluated until their arguments are available. So `let x = e in \y -> ...` allocates immediately, then waits for an argument (and therefore reuses that same single allocation every time an argument is supplied), while `\y -> let x = e in ...` waits for an argument, then makes an allocation (and therefore makes a new allocation every time an argument is supplied). But absolutely no idea about question 1, I find that baffling.

Comment: Can you post the full code such that we can reproduce it?

Comment: Sure https://github.com/dnadales/sandbox/blob/56280b3ae8724bf020081650b4793888155c71c4/profiling/src/Lib.hs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

0. No, both `in_no_lambda` and `in_lambda` are optimized by GHC to compute the sum "outside" the `fmap`. That this happens even for `in_no_lambda` is because of the [full laziness optimization](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/9.6.1/docs/users_guide/using-optimisation.html#ghc-flag--ffull-laziness).
1. I'm not very familiar with the inner workings of cost centres, but looking at the behavior I believe it is just computing the sum once and then counting how many times that result is looked up, so only one of all those entries does any real computation.

I thought the actual difference in running time would become more clear when you look at the simplified Core (I've cleaned it up a bit to be almost real Haskell code):

```hs
go w ww =
  case w of
    [] -> I# ww
    y : ys -> case y of I# y1 -> go ys (ww +# y1)

in_lambda xs =
  map (let sum_xs = go xs 0# in \i -> $fNumInt_$c+ sum_xs i)

in_no_lambda xs eta
  let lvl = go xs 0# in
  map
    (\i -> case lvl of I# x -> case i of I# y -> I# (x +# y))
    eta
```

The main difference seemed to be that `in_lambda` contains a call to `$fNumInt_$c+` (which is the `+` function specialized to the type `Int`) whereas `in_no_lambda` uses the primitive `+#` directly which saves the overhead of one function call.

I thought this would explain the performance difference, but it turns out it must be something else. We can show that this doesn't explain the performance difference by manually using the `+#` primitive:

```
import GHC.Exts

[..]

aux_in_lambda :: [Int] -> Int -> Int
aux_in_lambda xs = let sum_xs = {-# SCC "sum_in_lambda" #-} sum xs
                   in \i -> case sum_xs of I# x -> case i of I# y -> I# (x +# y)
```

This doesn't speed up the `in_lambda` function.

In fact, I can make it exactly equivalent to `in_no_lambda` in the STG dump and the difference in running time still shows up in the profile. At this point I'm pretty sure it must be some kind of oddity in the cost centre profiling mechanism itself. I'm sure this time difference wouldn't show up in a real benchmark.

One thing that you might also have noticed is that `in_lambda` has the `let sum_xs = ...` inside the argument to `map`. This is, however, not a problem at all because it is not under a lambda and therefore will only be evaluated once. You can see this more clearly in the STG representation (this time I've not altered the code):

```hs
in_lambda =
    CCS_DONT_CARE \r [xs]
        let { sum_xs = CCCS \u [] $wgo1 xs 0#; } in
        let { sat = CCCS \r [i] $fNumInt_$c+ sum_xs i; } in  map sat;
```

It first allocates the `sum_xs` value and then the `sat` function which is finally passed as the first argument to map. (I also don't know what exactly those `CCS_DONT_CARE` and `CCCS` things are, except that they are related to the cost centre mechanism.)

Comment: Fantastic analysis. Thank you!